# Error in testing function call with Karma in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, karma-runner

I am trying to implement a very simple application with AngularJs based on the tutorial that there is in it's website. I want to perform unit testing with Karma.
My files:

**karma.conf.js**

```
module.exports = function(config) {
config.set({

    basePath: '',

    files: [
        'angular/angular.min.js',
        'angular/angular-resource.min.js',
        'angular/angular-route.min.js',
        'angular/angular-mocks.js',
        'app.module.js',
        'phone-list/phone-list.module.js',
        'phone-list/phone-list.component.js',
        'phone-detail/phone-detail.module.js',
        'phone-detail/phone-detail.component.js',
        'core/core.module.js',
        'core/phone/phone.module.js',
        'core/phone/phone.service.js',
        'phone-list/phone-list.component.spec.js'
    ],

    autoWatch: true,
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],
    browsers: ['Chrome', 'Firefox'],
    plugins: [
        'karma-chrome-launcher',
        'karma-firefox-launcher',
        'karma-jasmine'
    ]
});
};
```

**phone-list.component.js**

```
'use strict';
 angular.
 module('phoneList').
 component('phoneList', {
 templateUrl: 'phone-list/phone-list.template.html',
 controller: ['Phone', function PhoneListController(Phone) {
        var self = this;
        self.$onInit = initializeData;

        function initializeData () {
            self.orderProp = 'age';
            self.loadPhones();
        }

        function testFunction() {
            return 'test';
        }

        self.loadPhones = function() {
            self.phones = Phone.query(testFunction);
        };

    }
]
});
```

**phone-list.component.spec.js**

```
'use strict';

describe('phoneList', function() {

beforeEach(module('phoneList'));

describe('PhoneListController', function() {
  var ctrl, mockPhone, phoneData;

  phoneData = {
      "age": 1,
      "id": "motorola",
      "imageUrl": "img/phones/motorola.jpg",
      "name": "Motorola XOOM with Wi-Fi",
      "snippet": "The Next, Next Generation,Experience"
  };

  beforeEach(module('phoneList', function($provide) {
      mockPhone = {
          query: function () {
              return phoneData;
          }
      };
      $provide.value('Phone', mockPhone);
  }));

beforeEach(inject(function($componentController) {
    ctrl = $componentController('phoneList');
}));

  it('should initialize controller data and check a function call', function() {
    jasmine.addCustomEqualityTester(angular.equals);
    spyOn(ctrl, 'loadPhones').and.callThrough();
    spyOn(mockPhone, 'query').and.callThrough();
    ctrl.$onInit();
    expect(ctrl.loadPhones).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(ctrl.phones).toEqual(phoneData);
    expect(mockPhone.query).toHaveBeenCalledWith(jasmine.any(Function));
  });    
});
});
```

**phone.service.js**

```
angular
.module('core.phone')
.factory('Phone', ['$resource',
function ($resource) {
    return $resource('phones/phones.json', {}, {
        query: {
            method: 'GET',
            params: {phoneId: phones},
            isArray: true
        }
    });
}
]);
```

**package.json** at C:\WebstormProjects\testing\app\node_modules\karma

```
   {
  "_args": [
    [
      {
        "raw": "karma",
        "scope": null,
        "escapedName": "karma",
        "name": "karma",
        "rawSpec": "",
        "spec": "latest",
        "type": "tag"
      },
      "C:\\WebstormProjects\\testing\\app"
    ]
  ],
  "_from": "karma@latest",
  "_id": "karma@1.3.0",
  "_inCache": true,
  "_installable": true,
  "_location": "/karma",
  "_nodeVersion": "6.3.0",
  "_npmOperationalInternal": {
    "host": "packages-12-west.internal.npmjs.com",
    "tmp": "tmp/karma-1.3.0.tgz_1473445878695_0.6908389490563422"
  },
  "_npmUser": {
     ...
  },
  "_npmVersion": "3.10.3",
  "_phantomChildren": {},
  "_requested": {
    "raw": "karma",
    "scope": null,
    "escapedName": "karma",
    "name": "karma",
    "rawSpec": "",
    "spec": "latest",
    "type": "tag"
  },
  "_requiredBy": [
    "#DEV:/",
    "#USER"
  ],
  "_resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/karma/-/karma-1.3.0.tgz",
  "_shasum": "b2b94e8f499fadd0069d54f9aef4a4d48ec5cc1f",
  "_shrinkwrap": null,
  "_spec": "karma",
  "_where": "C:\\WebstormProjects\\testing\\app",
  "author": {
    ...
  },
  "bin": {
    "karma": "./bin/karma"
  },
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/karma-runner/karma/issues"
  },
  "config": {
    "ghooks": {
      "pre-commit": "npm run lint",
      "commit-msg": "validate-commit-msg"
    }
  },
  "contributors": [
    ....

  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "bluebird": "^3.3.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.12.4",
    "chokidar": "^1.4.1",
    "colors": "^1.1.0",
    "combine-lists": "^1.0.0",
    "connect": "^3.3.5",
    "core-js": "^2.2.0",
    "di": "^0.0.1",
    "dom-serialize": "^2.2.0",
    "expand-braces": "^0.1.1",
    "glob": "^7.0.3",
    "graceful-fs": "^4.1.2",
    "http-proxy": "^1.13.0",
    "isbinaryfile": "^3.0.0",
    "lodash": "^3.8.0",
    "log4js": "^0.6.31",
    "mime": "^1.3.4",
    "minimatch": "^3.0.0",
    "optimist": "^0.6.1",
    "qjobs": "^1.1.4",
    "range-parser": "^1.2.0",
    "rimraf": "^2.3.3",
    "socket.io": "1.4.7",
    "source-map": "^0.5.3",
    "tmp": "0.0.28",
    "useragent": "^2.1.9"
  },
  "description": "Spectacular Test Runner for JavaScript.",
  "devDependencies": {
    "LiveScript": "^1.3.0",
    "babel": "^6.5.2",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.9.0",
    "babel-register": "^6.9.0",
    "chai": "^3.3.0",
    "chai-as-promised": "^5.0.0",
    "chai-subset": "^1.2.2",
    "coffee-script": "^1.9.2",
    "cucumber": "^1.2.0",
    "eslint": "^2.3.0",
    "eslint-config-standard": "^5.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^1.0.8",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^5.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-standard": "^1.3.1",
    "ghooks": "^1.1.0",
    "grunt": "^1.0.0",
    "grunt-auto-release": "^0.0.6",
    "grunt-browserify": "^5.0.0",
    "grunt-bump": "^0.8.0",
    "grunt-cli": "^1.1.0",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "^1.0.0",
    "grunt-conventional-changelog": "^6.0.1",
    "grunt-conventional-github-releaser": "^1.0.0",
    "grunt-cucumberjs": "^0.10.2",
    "grunt-eslint": "^18.0.0",
    "grunt-mocha-test": "^0.12.7",
    "grunt-npm": "0.0.2",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.3.4",
    "json3": "^3.3.2",
    "karma-browserify": "^5.0.1",
    "karma-browserstack-launcher": "^1.0.0",
    "karma-chai": "^0.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "*",
    "karma-coffee-preprocessor": "*",
    "karma-commonjs": "*",
    "karma-coverage": "*",
    "karma-firefox-launcher": "*",
    "karma-growl-reporter": "*",
    "karma-html2js-preprocessor": "*",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-junit-reporter": "*",
    "karma-live-preprocessor": "*",
    "karma-mocha": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-mocha-reporter": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-ng-scenario": "*",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "*",
    "karma-qunit": "*",
    "karma-requirejs": "*",
    "karma-sauce-launcher": "*",
    "karma-script-launcher": "^1.0.0",
    "load-grunt-tasks": "^3.1.0",
    "mkdirp": "^0.5.0",
    "mocha": "^2.4.1",
    "mocks": "^0.0.15",
    "phantomjs-prebuilt": "^2.1.3",
    "proxyquire": "^1.5.0",
    "qunitjs": "^1.21.0",
    "requirejs": "^2.1.20",
    "sinon": "^1.17.5",
    "sinon-chai": "^2.7.0",
    "supertest": "^2.0.0",
    "supertest-as-promised": "^3.0.0",
    "timer-shim": "^0.3.0",
    "validate-commit-msg": "^2.4.1",
    "which": "^1.1.1"
  },
  "directories": {},
  "dist": {
    "shasum": "b2b94e8f499fadd0069d54f9aef4a4d48ec5cc1f",
    "tarball": "https://registry.npmjs.org/karma/-/karma-1.3.0.tgz"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "0.10 || 0.12 || 4 || 5 || 6"
  },
  "gitHead": "9cd65cd0d9b063d54953013105904e9b55822f47",
  "homepage": "http://karma-runner.github.io/",
  "keywords": [
    "karma",
    "spectacular",
    "runner",
    "karma",
    "js",
    "javascript",
    "testing",
    "test",
    "remote",
    "execution"
  ],
  "license": "MIT",
  "main": "./lib/index",
  "maintainers": [
    ...
  ],
  "name": "karma",
  "optionalDependencies": {},
  "readme": "ERROR: No README data found!",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git://github.com/karma-runner/karma.git"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "appveyor": "npm run lint && npm run build && npm run test:appveyor",
    "build": "grunt build",
    "init": "rm -rf node_modules/karma && cd node_modules && ln -nsf ../ karma && cd ../",
    "init:windows": "(IF EXIST node_modules\\karma (rmdir node_modules\\karma /S /q)) && npm run link",
    "link": "node --eval \"path=require('path'); require('fs').symlinkSync(path.resolve(__dirname), path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules', 'karma'), 'junction')\"",
    "lint": "grunt lint",
    "test": "grunt test",
    "test:appveyor": "grunt test-appveyor",
    "test:integration": "./scripts/integration-tests.sh",
    "travis": "npm run lint && npm run build && npm test && npm run test:integration",
    "unlink": "node --eval \"require('fs').unlinkSync(require('path').resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules', 'karma'))\""
  },
  "version": "1.3.0"
}
```

When I run the tests, I get the following error:

```
   Expected spy query to have been called with [ <jasmine.any(Function)> ] but actual calls were [ Function ].
        at Object.<anonymous> (phone-list/phone-list.component.spec.js:40:31)
```

Is my testing strategy wrong? Why I get this error?

Comment: Can you show the dependencies part of your `package.json` and your `bower.json`?

Comment: I don't have these files. I have a node modules folder. I installed karma as shown here: https://karma-runner.github.io/1.0/intro/installation.html `npm install karma --save-dev`

Comment: You should have a `package.json` somewhere.

Comment: Updated question with package.json at C:\WebstormProjects\testing\app\node_modules\karma

Comment: I don't have time now, but will take a look at it tomorrow, if still unsolved.

Comment: Still need help with this?

Comment: Yes, I don't understand the error message. It is called with a function.